# Get COUNT() AND COUNT(DISTINCT()) values across 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a COUNT(*) from a joined table "Table2" where the dates are common PLUS a COUNT(DISTINCT(CID)) from "Table1" and grouped by the common year-month:

```
Table1
---------------
cid |  date   | 
----|---------|
321 | 2016-01 |
----|---------|
423 | 2016-01 |
----|---------|
324 | 2016-01 |
----|---------|
546 | 2015-12 |
----|---------|

Table2
---------------
id  | dateEnq | 
----|---------|
3   | 2016-01 |
----|---------|
6   | 2016-01 |
----|---------|
24  | 2015-12 |
----|---------|
36  | 2015-12 |
----|---------|
```

MySQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (t1.cid) ) AS users,
SUBSTR(DATE(t1.date),1,7) AS month,
COUNT(t2.dateEnq) AS enquiries
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON SUBSTR(t2.dateEnq, 1, 7 ) = SUBSTR(t1.date, 1, 7 )
GROUP BY SUBSTR(DATE(t1.date),1,7)
```

This is the result I get, but the enquiries values are just way wrong, I think it is not counting the values from Table2, they should be like 3, 10, 25 per row.

How do I get the monthly count from Table2?

```
users | month    | enquiries|
------|----------|-----------
7237  | 2015-10  | 8374     |
12597 | 2015-11  | 30066    |
12980 | 2015-12  | 15514    |
11305 | 2016-01  | 128169   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "counts" are inflated because it's a partial cross product. For a given month, every row from `t1` is matched to every row for that same month from `t2`.

One option is to get the counts before you do the join.  As an example, using inline views:

```
SELECT c1.users
     , c1.month
     , c2.enquiries
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.cid)    AS `users`
              , SUBSTR(DATE(t1.date),1,7) AS `month`
           FROM table1 t1
          GROUP BY SUBSTR(DATE(t1.date),1,7)
       ) c1
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(t2.dateEnq)         AS `enquiries`
              , SUBSTR(DATE(t2.date),1,7) AS `month`
           FROM table2 t2 
          GROUP BY SUBSTR(DATE(t2.date),1,7)
       ) c2
    ON c2.month = c1.month
 ORDER BY c1.month
```

This isn't the only way (or even necessarily the best way) to get this result. There are other query patterns that will achieve equivalent results.

If there's a possibility to have zero `enquiries` for a given `month`, then to get that zero count returned, we can tweak that query so it's an outer join, and then replace any NULL value (for a missing row) with a zero in the outer query:

```
SELECT c1.users
     , c1.month
     , IFNULL(c2.enquiries,0) AS `enquiries`
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.cid)    AS `users`
              , SUBSTR(DATE(t1.date),1,7) AS `month`
           FROM table1 t1
          GROUP BY SUBSTR(DATE(t1.date),1,7)
       ) c1
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(t2.dateEnq)         AS `enquiries`
              , SUBSTR(DATE(t2.date),1,7) AS `month`
           FROM table2 t2 
          GROUP BY SUBSTR(DATE(t2.date),1,7)
       ) c2
    ON c2.month = c1.month
 ORDER BY c1.month
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying... your first query works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, there is a possibility of 0, thanks that also works great.

Comment: ... I could have explained... because the inline view queries are guaranteed to have unique values of `month` (due to the `GROUP BY` clause), the join between the two will have (at most) one row each for a given month. So the counts won't be inflated. You can run the inline view queries separately to test. Once you understand how the original query is generating the inflated counts, the question is really how do I write a SQL statement that doesn't generate a partial cross product. This is just an example of one approach. You might leave the question open, and see if you get a better answer.

Comment: Performance of different queries is going to be influenced by the cardinality, available indexes, query plan. When those inline view queries only return 4 rows, the join is pretty fast. But if those queries return a bloatload of rows, then performance can go downhill fast. The outer join works if one of the sets can be missing a month. If either of the sets is missing a month, and you want then the query to return zero counts, the query has to be a little more elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough explanation, I didn't know how to get the sub queries wrapped together in one "Main query" I guessed it should have that structure but ...... SQL is not very intuitive :)

Comment: The *inline view* query is a useful tool to have in the SQL toolbelt. It's essentially the same as a stored view. It's a query in the `FROM` clause , and you're referencing the resultset from a query like it was a table. (The MySQL documentation actually refers to the inline view query as a "derived table".) It's also possible to use subqueries elsewhere in a query. Not every subquery is an inline view query.